# Issue with the datatable: it becomes misaligned when there's a large amount of data, causing it to overflow the screen

Tags: html, css, reactjs, datatable, jsx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z7lK.png)How can I solve the issue of a "datatable" getting misaligned and overflowing the predetermined screen when a substantial amount of information is input? I'm seeking effective methods to maintain proper structure and design even as the data becomes extensive. Are there specific strategies, such as adjusting the table's height, implementing responsive design, or considering pagination, that would be helpful in this scenario? I appreciate any guidance on addressing this problem and ensuring that the "datatable" retains its visual integrity regardless of the amount of data presented.

```
export function Property() {
  return (
    <section className="sections" id="section__property">
      <h1>Inmueble</h1>

      <div className="table-zone">
        <Datatables />
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

```
const columns = ["Name", "Company", "City", "State"];

const data = [
  ["Joe James", "Test Corp", "Yonkers", "NY"],
  ["John Walsh", "Test Corp", "Hartford", "CT"],
  ["Bob Herm", "Test Corp", "Tampa", "FL"],
  ["James Houston", "Test Corp", "Dallas", "TX"],
  ["Joe James", "Test Corp", "Yonkers", "NY"],
  ["Bob Herm", "Test Corp", "Tampa", "FL"],
  ["James Houston", "Test Corp", "Dallas", "TX"],
];

const options = {
  filterType: "checkbox",
};

export function Datatables() {
  return (
    // <div id="table">
    <MUIDataTable
      title={"Inmuebles Disponibles"}
      data={data}
      columns={columns}
      options={options}
    />
    // </div>
  );
}
```

```
.sections{
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    & h1{
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    & .table-zone{
        // display: flex;
        // justify-content: center;
        // align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 70%;
        background-color: rgb(194, 194, 194);
        // overflow: auto;
        
    }

}
```